# Accessing diffrent websites on separate docker containers based by dns address

Tags: docker, dns, hosting, virtualhost, nas

I'm trying to host couple websites on my nas which will be accessible from public.

My plan is:

1. Use DDNS to translate domain name (website1.dns.org, website2.dns.org) to the same external ip address (XXX.YYY.ZZZ.QQQ)
2. Port forward on my router (port 80 -> port 88 on my NAS)
3. Host couple websites on separate containers on my NAS

Problem - I dont know how to redirect user which demands website1 to container1
and user which demands website2 to container2 using the same external ip address. I have read about virutal hosts but that demands one container with web server (nginx or apache). It is necessary for me to have separate containers

Comment: You need a signle-point-entry web server that'll separate traffic by `Host` HTTP header (vhost, that is). You can make it so that it'll forward requests to other containers on the NAS. In other words, you can have separate containers for your applications and another one separate as an entry point web server. Such web server usually called a reverse-proxy.

Comment: did you resolve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

As @anemyte commented you can use a reverse proxy to route requests based on any number of Layer 7 parameters present in the request, like headers.
For example, you can use Nginx as a reverse proxy that by the DNS name provided will route to application1 and with another route to application2 and so forth.
do not confuse with load balancer which ussually routes to the same type of application and "just" as its name balances the load between the instances.
here's an example of how you can configure such a thing:

You can separate each service (one of the 3 containers) to a server in the nginx configuration file and for each one specify the DNS under `domain_name`

```
http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name domain_name1;

        location / {
            proxy_pass         http://nas-address:container1-port;
        }
    }
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name domain_name2;

        location / {
            proxy_pass         http://nas-address:container2-port;
        }
    }
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name domain_name3;

        location / {
            proxy_pass         http://nas-address:container3-port;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer which dipicts in more details: https://serverfault.com/questions/579285/how-to-proxy-a-server-based-on-domain-name-of-request-using-nginx

nginx documentation on the subject: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/

an article by redhat on using nginx as reverse proxy: https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/setting-reverse-proxies-nginx

Hope this was usefull